# Enable to submit a form after checkbox length check in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that check if one or more checkbox is checked. If yes, the form is submitted. If no, I would like to display an alert.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var check = $('#form').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    if(check == 0) { alert('You must select one checkbox or more.'); }
    else { alert('Submit'); $('#form').submit(); }
});
```

**Problem is the following:**
If I checked one or more checkboxes, I have the `alert('Submit')` in loop...

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: this is because you are submitting form again and again with doing `$('#form').submit();` on else part

Comment: @singhakash: I suspected that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) { 
        alert('You must select one checkbox or more.');
        return false;
    }else{
        alert('Submit');
    }
});
```

Your code is not working because you are triggering the submit event into the same submit event handler...
Look at this scenario:

- You submitted the form;
- You checked if you have checkbox`s checked;
- You submitted the form (again, so...);
- You checked if you have checkbox`s checked (again);
- You submitted the form (again);
- (And again)
- (And again)
- (And again)

Sorry for my english...lol

Comment: It works but why my code did not work? I would like to understand my problem. Thanks.